# Netezza Get Row Count Of A Big Table Using Meta/System Tables

Tags: netezza

I have several big tables in Netezza (tens of terabytes of data).

I am trying to find a way to count rows in these tables using system / meta tables.

I know I could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename;
```

But that is slow and puts a lot of load on the Netezza appliance. I need to be counting rows in these big tables on a regular basis so I don't want to affect performance for other important queries that are running.

I found this query:

```
SELECT RELNAME TABLE_NAME,
CASE
WHEN RELTUPLES < 0
THEN ((2^32) * RELREFS) + ((2^32) + RELTUPLES )
ELSE ((2^32) * RELREFS) + ( RELTUPLES )
END NUM_ROWS
FROM
_T_CLASS,
_T_OBJECT
WHERE
_T_OBJECT.OBJID=_T_CLASS.OID AND
_T_OBJECT.OBJCLASS=4905 — DISPLAY ONLY TABLES
AND RELNAME = UPPER('<TABLE NAME>');
```

Which almost works. The problem with this query is that it doesn't deal with the fact there could be updated / deleted rows.

Since Netezza is keeping deleted rows in a database until grooming happens, I am getting wrong row counts.

Is there a query which would give me a correct row count taking into account deleted rows?

Answer (score 1):

There's no system table or view that I know of that is always guaranteed to have an accurate row count for tables that accounts for deleted rows.

One compromise solution would be to create a very thin materialized view (i.e. a single column) from the base table.  You can then count over the mview to get an accurate row count, and this should be much faster than counting over the base table.  In fact, you can count(1) over the base table and the optimizer will automatically redirect you to the mview behind the scenes.

The downside is the usual for a materialized views;you're paying the IO cost to keep it updated.  If your table is wide enough, and if the feature is useful enough, then it could easily be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about _T_OBJECT.OBJCLASS=4905 part of the query , there can have tables with a different object class also.
Use this instead,

> ```
> SELECT RELNAME TABLE_NAME,
> CASE
> WHEN RELTUPLES < 0
> THEN ((2^32) * RELREFS) + ((2^32) + RELTUPLES )
> ELSE ((2^32) * RELREFS) + ( RELTUPLES )
> END NUM_ROWS
> FROM
> _T_CLASS,
> _T_OBJECT,
> _t_object_classes
> WHERE
> _T_OBJECT.OBJID=_T_CLASS.OID AND _T_OBJECT.OBJCLASS=_t_object_classes.OBJCLASS AND
> _t_object_classes.OBJREFCLASS=4905   -- DISPLAY ONLY TABLES
> AND RELNAME= UPPER('<TABLE NAME>');
> ```

Comment: Remove "AND RELNAME= UPPER('<TABLE NAME>')" and try. We can get all table

Answer (score 0):

Given below is not using system tables, but can reduce the performance impact to appliance.
Rather than returning a potentially huge result set back to your application, which might take a long time, simply return a count of the number of rows that would have been returned by your SQL.

Give a try for the below:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS "# Of Rows Your Query Returned"
FROM
(
 SELECT * from TABLE_NAME;
) AS "Wrapper";
```